# What does the sec-fetch-site header mean? Why is the Origin header undefined?

Tags: http-headers, cors, fetch-api, same-origin-policy, sec-fetch-site

I have an `API` endpoint that I call from my React app. That `API` is on the same domain. Something like:

```
https://www.example.com
https://www.example.com/api/update-something
```

I use `cross-fetch` to do that request.

I was expecting to see an `Origin` header on my server logs. Infact, I was expecting to see `Origin: https://www.example.com` .

But here is what I get:

```
Origin: undefined

// AND I ALSO GET THESE HEADERS

"sec-fetch-dest":"empty",
"sec-fetch-mode":"cors",
"sec-fetch-site":"same-origin"
```

What do they mean? It's like the `Origin` check was already made?

For example: if I get `sec-fetch-site: cross-site` it means that the call was generate in another website/domain? Is that correct?

Reference:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Sec-Fetch-Site

```
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> I have an API endpoint that I call from my React app. That API is on the same domain. … I was expecting to see an `Origin` header on my server logs.

Browsers send no `Origin` in same-origin `GET` requests, per Fetch spec requirements. ✳️

> it's like the Origin check was already made

Yes — browsers know:

- the origin of the code making the request
- the origin of the resource for which the request is being made
- the request method

…and browsers check all those before deciding whether to add the `Origin` header; and they don’t add the `Origin` header if the origins match and the method is `GET`.

> ```
> // AND I ALSO GET THESE HEADERS
> "sec-fetch-dest":"empty",
> "sec-fetch-mode":"cors",
> "sec-fetch-site":"same-origin"
> ```
>
> What do they mean? … For example: if I get `sec-fetch-site: cross-site` it means that the call was generate in another website/domain? Is that correct?

https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-fetch-metadata/#sec-fetch-site-header has details:

| Sec-Fetch-Site value | What the value indicates |
| --- | --- |
| same-origin | The origin to which the request is being made matches the origin of the code making the request. |
| same-site | The origin to which the request is being made and the origin of the code making the request have the same *“registrable domain”* (sometimes also referred to as the *“same eTLD+1”* or *“same effective top-level domain plus one”*); so, for example, `https://subdomain.example.com` and `https://example.com` are same-site (even though not same-origin). |
| cross-site | The origin to which the request is being made and the origin of the code making the request are neither same-origin nor even same-site but instead have different registrable domains. |
| none | The request wasn’t initiated programatically by frontend code (for example, not by an XHR/fetch/ajax call) but instead initiated by normal user navigation — that is, by a user doing something like directly putting an address into the browser URL bar, or clicking on a hyperlink. |

---

✳️ Spec requirements causing the `Origin` header to be omitted in same-origin `GET` requests:

Whether or not the `Origin` header gets added ultimately depends on the request’s [“response tainting”](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-request-response-tainting), the value of which starts out as "`basic`", and which, for same-origin requests, the Fetch algorithm keeps sets to "`basic`", per step 12 of the [“Main fetch” algorithm](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#main-fetch):

> ↪ ***request*’s current url’s origin is same origin with *request*’s
> origin, and *request*’s response tainting is "`basic`"**
> …
>
> 1. Set request’s response tainting to "`basic`".
> 2. Return the result of running [scheme fetch](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-scheme-fetch) given *fetchParams*.

Running [scheme fetch](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-scheme-fetch) causes the [append a request `Origin` header](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#append-a-request-origin-header) algorithm to get invoked, and that causes the `Origin` header to be added only if at least one of the following is true:

- the request’s response tainting is "`cors`"
- the request’s mode is "`websocket`"
- the request’s method is neither `GET` nor `HEAD`

But for same-origin `GET`, the response tainting isn’t `cors` (rather, per the requirements above, it’s `basic`), the request mode isn’t `websocket`, and of course the method isn’t neither `GET` nor `HEAD` (it’s `GET`); thus, the algorithm requires browsers to not add an `Origin` header.

Comment: I'm also seeing this behavior for a web app rendered in an iframe (that has same-origin fetch request), but the method is POST instead of GET. Should it also be omitting the origin header when the method is POST?

Comment: @danludwig You may want to consider posting a separate question about that. Without seeing a reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example with code and the actual request and response headers, all that anybody here can do is just speculate. But per-spec, a POST request from a fetch call should pretty much always have an Origin header, unless no-cors mode has been set for the request.

Answer (score 0):

The Origin header is sent with CORS requests, as well as with POST requests.
The Origin header is not set on Fetch requests with a method of HEAD or GET

From:
[Origin header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin)

Comment: And the `sec-fetch` headers are also sent?

Comment: Yes, they are also sent.